# Plotting Streamline in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I was trying to plot this stream function in MATLAB:

```
psi=lambda*X*Y+0.5*omega*(Y*Y*exp(2*lambda*t)+X*X*exp(-2*lambda*t)
```

I wrote a code:

```
lambda = 1;
omega = 0.4;
t=2;

[X,Y]= meshgrid(linspace(-0.05,0.05,100),linspace(0,0.15,100));
Z = lambda*X*Y+0.5*omega*(Y*Y*exp(2*lambda*t)+X*X*exp(-2*lambda*t));
contour(X,Y,Z,100)
[C,h] = contour(X,Y,Z);

set(h,'ShowText','on','TextStep',get(h,'LevelStep')*2)
colormap cool
```

And it works, but the result is just some straight lines like:
[image]

I 'm concerned, because the plot shouln't look like this.

Comment: What should the plot look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stream function is taking matrix products of the `X` and `Y` mesh matrices by using the `*` operator, rather than working on each element. The result of that is essentially meaningless. Use the elementwise operator `.*` and the stream function will then be a scalar function of two coordinates.

```
Z = lambda*X.*Y+0.5*omega*(Y.*Y*exp(2*lambda*t)+X.*X*exp(-2*lambda*t));
```

Still not a very interesting one, but a sensible thing to plot contours of:

[image: Streamlines]